# Let Carousel Move Automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that carousel move automatically when the home page is opened;

Currently the carousel look fine but it still not moving. it move only when the right/left buttons are clicked on

the carousel contains multi items that should moving automatically without needing to click on rght/left buttons

here's demo :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });

    ResCarouselSize();




    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);


            if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                incno = itemsSplit[3];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                incno = itemsSplit[2];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                incno = itemsSplit[1];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else {
                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }


    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }

});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; width: 100%; position:relative; }
    .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item { float: left;}
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:calc(50% - 20px); }
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
    .MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }
    
        .MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst"><</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">></button>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
         <br/><br/><br/>
         <hr/>
         <p>Settings</p>
         <p>Change data items for xs,sm,md and lg display items respectively. Ex:data-items="1,3,5,6"</p>
         <p>Change data slide for slides per click Ex:data-slide="1"</p>
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey abdul , please use jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/7uLqtda8/2/) so that its easy for anyone to get into the problem quicker.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7uLqtda8/22/

Answer (score 0):

For this I would suggest using bootstrap as it comes with all the bells and whistles and all you would need is to add it.

Please check https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#carouselExampleControls